# how ctypes bitfields really work?

Tags: python, bit-fields

In python, using ctypes, following is legal:

```
from ctypes import *
class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
     ("y", c_int)]

p = POINT(10,20)
sum = p.x + p.y
```

But how this works? I mean how p.x is perfectly legal? What kind of trick provides this?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize an instance of a subclass the `Structure` class it reads the `_fields_` and associates attributes based on the field names in that list.

This is all done in C, so if you want to see exactly how it is done you need to use the source, in particular the definition of the `Struct_type`, and the `_init_pos_args` function https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L4021